# How to render form elements using form alter

Tags: 6

I need to render contact form field elements using `form_alter` function. When I print `$content` variable in tpl file, the contact form loads entirely, instead of that I need to render fields separately like `drupal_render(drupal_get_form(form['name']))`

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you are implementing `hook_form_alter()` you are not going to use any template.